# Strange font size behavior in nested html list (mobile)

Tags: html, css, html-lists

I feel dumb asking this question, but I have a problem with the font size in a nested html list that I have not been able to figure out. The problem only appears when I open the web page on my cell phone. I have tested the web page on my cell phone using Chrome for Android, an iPad (using Safari and Chrome) and a laptop. The problem only appears on the cell phone.

I have the following code:

```
<html>
<head>
<title>Test</title>
<style >
    #body-text {
        font-size: 15px;
        line-height: 1.5em;
        max-width: 90%;
        margin: auto;
        }
    #body-text ul {
        list-style-type: disc;
        }
    #body-text ul > li {
        list-style-position: outside;
        }
    #body-text ul > li > ul {
        list-style-type: circle;
        }
    #body-text ul > li > ul > li {
        list-style-position: outside;
        }
</style>
</head>
<body>            
<div id="body-text">
    <p style="margin-bottom:5px;">Check this list: </p>
    <ul>
        <li>This is parent 1 (details 1):
        <ul>
            <li>This is child 1, long text here (more long text here too).</li>
            <li>This is child 2, long text here (more long text here too).</li>
        </ul>
        </li>
    </ul>
    <ul>
        <li>This is parent 2 (details 2):
        <ul>
            <li>This is child 3, long text here (more long text here too).</li>
        </ul>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

For certain variations of the *text* in the code above, I obtain different font sizes. For example, if I comment the line `<li>This is child 2, long text here (more long text here too).</li>`, or just make it shorter to e.g. `<li>This is child 2, long text here.</li>`, I get the intended font size (15). However, the code as it is gives a larger font size.

The problem is that the list is the only part of the web page that has this behavior. Other parts of the web page (not included here) remain with their intended font size.

Any ideas about what is happening?

Comment: try #body-text li {font-size: 15px}

Comment: It seems you didn't add meta viewport [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Mobile/Viewport_meta_tag) has a nice article.

Comment: @Pangloss The meta viewport makes all the web page' style consistent. However, for that to work, I need to have specified a layout for mobile devices (or smaller screens), which is not my case. Because I don't have that extra options, when using meta viewport the site gets completely disorganized.

Answer (score 0):

have you tried using css reset?

> The goal of a reset stylesheet is to reduce browser inconsistencies in things like default line heights, margins and font sizes of headings, and so on

you can read the document [here](http://meyerweb.com/eric/tools/css/reset/)

http://meyerweb.com/eric/tools/css/reset/